# what's the best solution of updating a record with authentication and invoking beforeSave in Yii framework?

Tags: php, yii

I'm on the yii api document, there's a method named `saveAttributes()` used to update a couple of fields. my situation is just update a specific field `status` through this method.

```
ModelName::model()->findByPk($id)->saveAttributes(array('status' => 1));
```

but seems `saveAttributes` didn't invoke `beforeSave()` method in the model, so what's the best solution to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$model = ModelName::model()->findByPk($id);
$model->status = 1;
$model->save();
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord/#saveAttributes-detail